# Нужна библиотека для написания приложения для андроида C++

Tags: c++

нужно сделать приложения для андроида с GUI на C++, подскажите какую-нибудь библиотеку для этого. SFML не советуйте, ибо там нету кнопок, переключателей (типо on/off) и не понятно как собрать апк

Comment: Насколько я помню по рекламе - Qt хвалятся, что умеет создавать мобильные версии. Но сам я в культях не разбираюсь - мне их лицензия не нравится :-).

Comment: используем для сенсорного экрана под Ubuntu в варианте с SFML, очень неплохо, но слабоват дизайнер: https://tgui.eu, а apk по любому хоть Qt, хоть SFML надо собирать через NDK, правда QtCreator это автоматизирует